# Re-build query to use table with similar data but with no every dates in between

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following query:

```
select * from
  (
     SELECT    o.geo_code, 
               o.OP_FCTY_1_CODE, 
               o.object_id,                    
               o.code,                    
               e.DAYTIME,
               e.END_DATE, 
               e.EVENT_REASON,
               e.MASS
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY                                 
                    o.object_id, 
                    e.DAYTIME, 
                    e.END_DATE
                 ORDER BY o.object_id
                                 ) AS DuplicateCount
            from                
               deferment e, ov o, FCTY_CLASS_1 c, current_status s
                 WHERE  e.object_id = o.object_id
                 AND    o.op_fcty_1_id = c.object_id
                 AND    o.object_id = s.object_id
                 AND    c.production_day = s.prod_day 
                 AND    s.status in ('ACT', 'STN')
                 AND    o.class = 'P'
                 AND    c.production_day BETWEEN (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(o.DAYTIME, 'ddmmyyyy'),'ddmmyyyy')) AND (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(NVL(o.end_date, SYSDATE),'ddmmyyyy'),'ddmmyyyy'))
                 AND    c.production_day BETWEEN (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(e.DAYTIME, 'ddmmyyyy'),'ddmmyyyy')) AND (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(NVL(e.end_date, SYSDATE),'ddmmyyyy'),'ddmmyyyy'))
                 AND    c.production_day BETWEEN '01-Jan-19' and '31-Jan-19'
  ) Where DuplicateCount = 1;
```

The problem here it's runs slow because of current_status s table which has following format:

```
    code prod_day   status
    D10 01-Nov-01   STN
    D10 02-Nov-01   STN
    D10 03-Nov-01   STN
    D10 04-Nov-01   STN
    D10 04-Nov-01   ACT
    D10 05-Nov-01   ACT
    D10 06-Nov-01   ACT
    D10 07-Nov-01   ACT
    D10 08-Nov-01   STN
    D10 09-Nov-01   STN
    D23 01-Nov-18   STN
    D23 02-Jul-18   STN
    D23 03-Jul-18   STN
    D23 04-Jul-18   ACT
    D23 05-Jul-18   ACT
    D23 06-Jul-18   ACT
    D23 07-Jul-18   ACT
    D23 08-Jul-18   STN
    D23 09-Jul-18   STN
```

and instead of current_status table I want to use last_status table which is similar the only difference is it doesn't have every day in between:

```
    code prod_day   status
    D10 01-Nov-01   STN
    D10 04-Nov-01   ACT
    D10 08-Nov-01   STN
    D23 04-Jul-18   ACT
    D23 08-Jul-18   STN
```

Is that possible to adopt last_status instead of current_status, I think it needs somehow rebuilt c.production_day = s.prod_day?

thanks,
S

Comment: I would suggest that you simplify the query you are running.  You seem to have unnecessary tables and columns that just clutter the question.

Comment: I thought for few days but current_status is real bottleneck, very slow view and I can't change it the only thing I need to adopt last_status which is very quick.

Comment: It's only a guess, but is `current_status` a view built from `last_status`? Maybe with recursive query? Can you show it? If so you could check date and `lead` date, but I don't know how you are partitioning data.

Comment: @Ponder Stibbons: no, last_status is not built from current_status. Recursive query can be a trick, what do you mean date and lead date?

Comment: [This](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fd97cb9ce2c2914aa02d45950b497999).

Comment: @Ponder Stibbons, Thanks for helping: I partitioning data by code, does it mean I need to add "select ls.*, lead(dt) over (partition by code order by dt) ldt from last_status ls"

Comment: Something like that. And maybe you need to check nulls for last rows ( `c.dt < s.ldt or s.ldt is null` ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197346/discussion-between-joe-green-and-ponder-stibbons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ponder Stibbons: Thanks a lot!!! this worked

```
select * 
  from fcty_class_1 c
  join (select ls.*, lead(dt) over (order by dt) ldt from last_status ls) s 
    on s.dt <= c.dt and (c.dt < s.ldt or s.ldt is null) and s.status in ('ACT', 'STN')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can then simply change your from clause to -

```
FROM  deferment e
INNER JOIN ov o on e.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN FCTY_CLASS_1 c ON o.op_fcty_1_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN last_status l ON o.object_id = l.object_id
                        AND c.production_day = l.prod_day 
                        AND l.status in ('ACT', 'STN')
```

Comment: It won't work then I miss data in between if I just simply  use c.production_day = l.prod_day

Comment: Please share the structure of last_status table.